# How to change terminal path in PhpStorm? Error running process: CreateProcess failed. Code 267?

Tags: terminal, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I've a problem with PhpStorm terminal path. My Laravel project is in another path. How can I change this path in the terminal?

[image]

Comment: We're programmers, we can read. Please read about [why you shouldn’t upload images of code or errors when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) and [how to create a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Did you read [this topic](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360007938460-Windows-git-bash-as-Terminal-shell-causes-Error-running-process-CreateProcess-failed-Code-267-)?

Comment: i can't find what should i do

Comment: There are several advices in a linked post on the official forum of the producer, try them. Also please search their forum for other issues of this kind. If it doesn't work, contact the authors, they have very good support for the product they sell.

Comment: The the path used by the built-in Terminal? It's `Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Tools | Terminal --> Start Directory`

Comment: thanks everyone i solved the problem by re-open the project again in new window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solved the problem by re-open the project again in new window

Answer (score 1):

In jetbrains IDE's change shell path to cmd.exe. Worked for Php Storm and Android Studio.

Here is the location:
**file –> setting –> Tools –> Terminal**

**change powershell.exe to cmd.exe**